# Calling "this" within Vue is returning Window

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. I have what seems like a super simple block of code, instantiating a new Vue object hooked to a div with id providers.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#providers', 
    data: {
        providers: []
    },
    created: () => {
        console.log(this);
    },
})
```

For some reason, when I call `console.log(this)` in created, it's returning `"Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}"`

I'm running `Vue 2.6.12`. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

I can't access any of my data in my lifecycle commands because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in the arrow function `=>`: it does not have its own bindings to `this` or `super`, and should not be used as methods (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

To bind `this` to a method use `function` long or short notation.

Long notation:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#providers', 
    data: {
        providers: []
    },
    created: function () {
        console.log(this);
    },
})
```

Short notation:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#providers', 
    data: {
        providers: []
    },
    created() {
        console.log(this);
    },
})
```